# How to get better at BASH and Linux commands?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I simply want to know how to get better at making BASH scripts and having a better handle of BASH scripting and commands in general. Like, which resources can I look up and learn from in order to do this?

Comment: This is sadly not how this site works, if you want an discussion you might have a look into [ubuntuforums.org](http://ubuntuforums.org). For a question and answer site your question is simply to broad and/or generates only opinion based answers.

Comment: Never the less you should maybe start [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html)

Comment: Have google at your side. I have a 2nd screen open on bash, python, perl, javascript, etc for all coding things I make (and yes I code for a living).

Comment: http://linuxcommand.org/ is a great start

Comment: Using https://www.shellcheck.net/ helps me troubleshoot things when I'm having trouble with a bash script. You'll get a wide variety of answers to a question like this but really the one thing they'll all have in common is you have to just jump in and do it. Start writing scripts. Script anything you can even if it's not the type of thing that usually calls for a script. You'll get better as you go.

Comment: Lots of info at https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend deciding what you want a given script to do, then searching for solutions step-by-step. It'll teach you each of the commands in isolation but you'll also learn how to best connect the script and deal with errors when you encounter them.

There's plenty books and sites on the subject but I think the best way to learn is a hands on, line by line approach. If you're not sure what you want your script to do, then you probably don't need to be better at it. Learn what you need to know, and if you want a reason to learn something then create a project or contribute to someone else's.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

you need to run commands by yourself to learn it and know how to use it

i advice you to read linux command line book 
it is a rich book you will sure benefit from it 
and try to run the commands in the book as he does

after it you can widen your knowledge but first read this book